# Couldn't access HDFS in spark cluster launched in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cluster-computing, hdfs, apache-spark

I launched a spark cluster in Ec2 with one slave and ebs-vol-size 50GB. I logged to one of the nodes of the clusters and went to /root/persistent-hdfs folder.
When I run the command, bin/hadoop fs -ls / I'm getting following error. it works from /root/ephermal folder though.

> [ec2-user@ip-172-31-36-159 persistent-hdfs]$ bin/hadoop fs -ls
>   /root/persistent-hdfs/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 69: ulimit: open files                                                                                        : cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
>   Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.
>
> 14/08/14 03:03:53 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-54-164-6-0.co                                                                                        mpute-1.amazonaws.com/172.31.35.144:9010. Already tried 0 time(s).
>
> 14/08/14 03:03:54 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-54-164-6-0.co                                                                                        mpute-1.amazonaws.com/172.31.35.144:9010. Already tried 1 time(s).
>
> 14/08/14 03:03:55 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-54-164-6-0.co                                                                                        mpute-1.amazonaws.com/172.31.35.144:9010. Already tried 2 time(s).
>
> 14/08/14 03:03:56 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-54-164-6-0.co                                                                                        mpute-1.amazonaws.com/172.31.35.144:9010. Already tried 3 time(s).
>   14/08/14 03:03:57 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-54-164-6-0.co                                                                                        mpute-1.amazonaws.com/172.31.35.144:9010. Already tried 4 time(s).
>
> 14/08/14 03:03:58 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-54-164-6-0.co                                                                                        mpute-1.amazonaws.com/172.31.35.144:9010. Already tried 5 time(s).
>
> 14/08/14 03:03:59 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-54-164-6-0.co                                                                                        mpute-1.amazonaws.com/172.31.35.144:9010. Already tried 6 time(s).
>
> 14/08/14 03:04:00 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-54-164-6-0.co                                                                                        mpute-1.amazonaws.com/172.31.35.144:9010. Already tried 7 time(s).
>
> 14/08/14 03:04:01 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-54-164-6-0.co                                                                                        mpute-1.amazonaws.com/172.31.35.144:9010. Already tried 8 time(s).
>
> 14/08/14 03:04:02 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-54-164-6-0.co                                                                                        mpute-1.amazonaws.com/172.31.35.144:9010. Already tried 9 time(s).
>
> Bad connection to FS. command aborted. exception: Call to ec2-54-164-6-0.compute                                                                                        -1.amazonaws.com/172.31.35.144:9010 failed on connection exception: java.net.Con                                                                                        nectException: Connection refused
>   [ec2-user@ip-172-31-36-159 persistent-hdfs]$

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to start the service.

```
persistent-hdfs/bin/start-all.sh
```